Bitcoin recovery company saying I have bitcoin in a frozen account
I’ve been approached by a company saying I have bitcoin in a frozen account, they can see that it belongs to me and want to get me to give the wallet details to transfer, I’m sure it’s a scam however 10-12 years ago maybe longer I did invest but it wasn’t like it was today it was a lot more difficult, I didn’t understand it and took the loss and didn’t want anything to do with online currency. Is there a way I can see if that money has done anything and if I can access it again ? I have no idea what platform and or the wallet that was used.

Most likely someone is trying to scam you out of an advance fee or trying to steal your identity. If they are very concretely addressing you and referencing an account that you actually had you might want to research them further, but the vast majority of these contacts are scams.


I’ve been approached by a company

You are right, so far as I can tell, this is always a scam.

Is there a way I can see if that money has done anything ...

Only if you have your own independent record of the Bitcoin addresses you used 10-12 years ago. Addresses of which you are certain and not just addresses given by strangers claiming to be a recovery company.

... and if I can access it again ?

Only if you have your own independent backup of the private keys or recovery phrase. Or your own record of complete account details for some known online service that is still in busines.

I have no idea what platform and or the wallet that was used.

Then you have no way to recover control over any money. Be extremely skeptical of anyone who says otherwise.
